# How can I set background and foreground terminal colors from CLI in Ubuntu 15.10?

Tags: command-line, themes, gnome-terminal, colors

I used to use [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/558280/changing-colour-of-text-and-background-of-terminal) to set my terminal colors to black on white from the command line as follows.

```
gconftool-2 --set "/apps/gnome-terminal/profiles/Default/use_theme_colors" --type bool false
gconftool-2 --set "/apps/gnome-terminal/profiles/Default/foreground_color" --type string "#000000000000"
gconftool-2 --set "/apps/gnome-terminal/profiles/Default/background_color" --type string "#FFFFFFFFDDDD"
```

Unfortunately, while the values are set when I run these commands in Ubuntu 15.10, the gnome-terminal colors do not change at all.

What is the correct way to set terminal colors from the CLI in 15.10?

Comment: See http://askubuntu.com/q/745676/398785.

Comment: Note: gnome-terminal has switched from gconf to gsettings/dconf.